# How to print prompt content for test purpose in Elvish shell?

Tags: shell, command-prompt, prompt, elvish

**related:** https://github.com/elves/elvish/issues/827

---

I'm on a prompt implementation and would like to test I correctly support `elvish`. I already do that for other shells by invoking their prompt variable/method, e.g.

`bash`

```
bash -ci 'echo $PS1'
```

`fish`

```
fish -c 'fish_prompt'
```

How can I print te prompt content in Elvish?

Answer (score 1):

From IRC I got some hint:

```
edit:prompt = { tilde-abbr $pwd; put '❱ ' }
```

But output is not the same as what elvish render:

```
~/.pure❱ $edit:prompt
▶ '~/.pure'
▶ '❱ '
```

I'm expecting:

```
~/.pure❱
```

The outputs from prompts are stringified and concatenated, you can achieve it with:

```
$edit:prompt | each $print~
```

However this doesn't work with  `elvish -c` or `echo ... | elvish`.

> elvish doesn't have an interactive mode per se. Unlike POSIX shells. I know it's been discussed before but I can't recall why the `edit:` namespace isn't available when doing `elvish -c '$edit:prompt | each $print~'`